# Как поместить matplotlib график функции в QWidget?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, matplotlib, qt-designer

Есть кнопка. По нажатию в `QWidget` должен появляться график функции *matplotlib*.

Кнопка не задействована, пустой график должен быть по умолчанию.

Само окно. В `QWidget` graph должен появляться график.

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from EngCalculatorUI import Ui_MainWindow
import math
from matplot import MplCanvas


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.canvas = MplCanvas(self, width=5, height=4, dpi=100)
        self.graph = self.canvas
        self.canvas.draw()
```

**matplot.py**

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class MplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        super(MplCanvas, self).__init__(fig)
```

[image: Приложение после запуска]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пожалуйста, всегда предоставляйте минимально-воспроизводимый пример.

Попробуйте так:

```
import random
import numpy as np

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(620, 584)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow) 
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.setStyleSheet("#centralwidget {background-color:  rgb(37, 37, 37);} ")
        
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.layout.setObjectName("layout")

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label.setStyleSheet("""
            QLabel {
                border-radius:  10px;
                background-color:  rgb(37, 37, 37);
                color:  rgb(255, 255, 255);
                font-size:  33px;
            }
        """)       
        
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("""
            QPushButton {
                border-radius:  10px;
                background-color:  rgb(87, 87, 87);
                color:  rgb(255, 255, 255);
                font-size:  22px;
            }
            QPushButton:pressed {
                background-color:  rgb(118, 118, 118);
            }
        """)

        self.pushButton.setFixedSize(120, 75)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 1, 1, 1, alignment=Qt.AlignRight)
        
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)                              # !!!
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.layout.addWidget(self.widget, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        
        self.layout.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
        self.layout.setColumnStretch(1, 0)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Построение графиков"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Построить"))


class MplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.fig = Figure()
        super(MplCanvas, self).__init__(self.fig, *args, **kwargs)

    def plot(self, labels, men_means, women_means, x, width):          
        self.fig.clear()                                               
        
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)                            
        
        rects1 = self.ax.bar(x - width/2, men_means, width, label='Men')
        rects2 = self.ax.bar(x + width/2, women_means, width, label='Women')
        self.ax.set_ylabel('Scores')
        self.ax.set_title('Scores by group and gender')
        self.ax.set_xticks(x)
        self.ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
        self.ax.legend()

        self.draw()                                                    
        

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.setMinimumSize(500, 400)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self._plot)

        self.canavas = MplCanvas()                                                     # !!! canavas
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canavas, self)
        
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.widget)                                         # !!! widget
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.canavas)                                            # !!! canavas
        self.layout.addWidget(self.toolbar)                                            # !!!
        self.toolbar.hide()   

    def _plot(self):
        labels = ['G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5']
        men_means = [ random.randrange(1, 100) for _ in range(5) ]
        women_means = [ random.randrange(1, 100) for _ in range(5) ]
        x = np.arange(len(labels))          # расположение столбиков
        width = 0.35                        # толщина столбика        
        
        self.canavas.plot(labels, men_means, women_means, x, width)    
        self.toolbar.show()      


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]